# Add all objects from one file to a list in another file

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following python file `constants.py` which stores a bunch of constants:

```
ONE = 1
TWO = 2
ANOTHER = "Test"
....
```

I'm trying to import all of the variables and add them to a list called `data`. This is what I have so far but if I add a constant to `constants.py` then I need to remember to add it to the `data` list:

```
from constants import *
data = [ONE, TWO, ANOTHER, ...]
```

Is there a better approach here?

Comment: create the list in `constants.py`. Beware global variables, btw. And beware `import *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to create the list in the `constants.py` file. It would like as follows:

```
ONE = 1
TWO = 2
ANOTHER = "Test"
....
data = [ONE, TWO, ANOTHER, ...]
```

Then you can simply import the list in your main file.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module. If your `constants.py` module contains:

```
ONE = 1
TWO = 2
ANOTHER = "Test"

__all__ = [ "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "ANOTHER" ]
```

You can import those as a module:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> constants = importlib.import_module('constants')
>>> constants.ONE
1
>>> constants.__dict__
{ ... 'ONE': 1, 'TWO': 2, 'THREE': 3, 'ANOTHER': 'Test'}
```

Due to the bloat of the "dunder" attributes (`__spec__`, `__builtins__` etc.), it can be useful to include the `__all__` attribute.

```
>>> constants_dict = { k: constants.__dict__[k] for k in constants.__all__ }
>>> constants_dict
{'ONE': 1, 'TWO': 2, 'THREE': 3, 'ANOTHER': 'Test'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variables start with uppercase, you can do this

```
ONE = 1
TWO = 2
ANOTHER = "Test"

exec('data = [' + ','.join([e for e in dir() if e[0].isupper()]) + ']')
```

and you don't have to remember to add them to `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar to other responses, but no other modules are required.

```
data = {name:getattr(constants, name) for name in dir(constants) if name[0] != '_'}
print(data) #Prints {'ANOTHER': 'Test', 'ONE': 1, 'TWO': 2}
```

Note that here the import statement should be `import constants` and not `from constants import *`.